# Want to change the font size of the widget in Android

Tags: android, tabs, widget

I have 4 Tabs in my activity and i want to change there font size but the problem is that only the First Tab change its font size but other three remains the same. **here is the code** plz help

```
package zubair.example.com.tabproject;

     import android.app.TabActivity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.LinearLayout;
     import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
     import android.widget.TabHost;
     import android.widget.TabWidget;
     import android.widget.TextView;







    public class Tabsmain extends TabActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener{


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TabHost tabHost;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_main);


        // Get TabHost Refference
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Set TabChangeListener called when tab changed
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;


        /************* TAB1 ************/
        // Create  Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("AboutUs")
                .setContent(intent);

        //Add intent to tab
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        /************* TAB2 ************/
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("our Firm")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        /************* TAB3 ************/
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Location")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        /************* TAB4 ************/
        // Create  Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab4.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator("ContactUs")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {


       TabWidget tw = (TabWidget)tabHost.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        View tabView = tw.getChildTabViewAt(0);
        TextView tv = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextSize(10);




        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            else if(i==1)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            else if(i==2)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            else if(i==3)
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
        }

        Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab: " + tabHost.getCurrentTab());

        if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==3)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab_bar, menu);
        return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

       }
```

Comment: do you want to change the font size of the tab that is selected or all the tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the text size for the first tab. Iterate through all the tabs and set the text size, like this

```
View tabView;
TextView tv;
for(int i = 0; i < tw.getTabCount(); i++){
    tabView = tw.getChildTabViewAt(i);
    tv = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextSize(10);
}
```

EDIT:

Also, this would probably be better to do in the `onCreate` method, rather than the `onTabChanged` method, since you only need to set the text size once.

Lastly, I'm not sure what this block of code was meant to do, but I don't think it actually accomplishes anything:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
    if(i==0)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    else if(i==1)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    else if(i==2)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    else if(i==3)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
}

Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab: " + tabHost.getCurrentTab());

if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==3)
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
```